# recycleview click listener ,subView click,view.getId() = -1

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-view, onclicklistener

I am using `RecycleView` to display data, in every ListItem has 3 button: `stat_btn`, `comment_btn` and `forward_btn`. I want to know which button the user clicked to do the different function, so in `onClick` method , i try to use view.getId() to show which button was clicked, but the `view.getId()` always return -1;

```
04-12 10:32:44.273 29382-29382/com.smartspace.magicmirror I/QUESTIONNAIREADAPTER: ---->>view.getid:-1
04-12 10:32:44.273 29382-29382/com.smartspace.magicmirror I/QUESTIONNAIREFRAGMENT: ---->>onItemClick: -1
```

here is my code:
the adapter

```
public class QuestionnaireAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<QuestionnaireAdapter.QuestionnaireViewHolder> implements OnClickListener{

    private static final String TAG = "QUESTIONNAIREADAPTER";

    public Context context;
    public Uri picTestUrl = Uri.parse("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/facebook/fresco/gh-pages/static/fresco-logo.png");
    public Uri picTestUrl2 = Uri.parse("http://magicwang.oss-cn-qingdao.aliyuncs.com/test.jpg");


    private OnRecycleViewItemClickListener mOnItemClickListener = null;

    public  interface OnRecycleViewItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(View view , String data);
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnRecycleViewItemClickListener listener) {
        this.mOnItemClickListener = listener;
    }

    public QuestionnaireAdapter(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public QuestionnaireViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.fragment_questionnaire_item, parent, false);

        QuestionnaireViewHolder questionnaireViewHolder =
                new QuestionnaireViewHolder(view);

        view.setOnClickListener(this);

        return questionnaireViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final QuestionnaireViewHolder holder, int position) {
        //holder.tv.setText("22");
        holder.dressImageView.setImageURI(picTestUrl2);
        holder.itemView.setTag("tag");

    }



    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 10;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.i(TAG,"---->>view.getid:" + v.getId());
        if (mOnItemClickListener != null) {
            mOnItemClickListener.onItemClick(v,(String)v.getTag());
        }
    }
```

ViewHolder

```
    class QuestionnaireViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        ImageView userIcon;
        TextView userName;
        TextView questionnaireTime;
        SimpleDraweeView dressImageView;

        //底部收藏、评论和转发按钮
        ImageView starBtn;
        ImageView commmentBtn;
        ImageView forwardBtn;


        public QuestionnaireViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            userIcon = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_icon);
            userName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_name);
            questionnaireTime = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.questionnaire_time);
            dressImageView = (SimpleDraweeView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.dress_imageview);

            starBtn = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.star_btn);
            commmentBtn = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.comment_btn);
            forwardBtn = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.forward_btn);

        }


    }
}
```

and the Fragment which use the adapter and the recyclerView

```
public class QuestionnaireFragment extends Fragment {

    public static final String TAG = "QUESTIONNAIREFRAGMENT";

    // TODO: Customize parameter argument names
    private static final String ARG_COLUMN_COUNT = "column-count";
    // TODO: Customize parameters
    private int mColumnCount = 1;
   // private OnListFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    private RecyclerView qusetionnaireRecyclerView;
    private QuestionnaireAdapter mQuestionnaireAdapter;


    /**
     * Mandatory empty constructor for the fragment manager to instantiate the
     * fragment (e.g. upon screen orientation changes).
     */
    public QuestionnaireFragment() {
    }

    // TODO: Customize parameter initialization
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public static QuestionnaireFragment newInstance(int columnCount) {
        QuestionnaireFragment fragment = new QuestionnaireFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_COLUMN_COUNT, columnCount);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mColumnCount = getArguments().getInt(ARG_COLUMN_COUNT);
        }

       mQuestionnaireAdapter = new QuestionnaireAdapter(AppApplication.getContext());
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_questionnaireitem_list, container, false);

        qusetionnaireRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.questionnaire_list);
        qusetionnaireRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        qusetionnaireRecyclerView.setAdapter(mQuestionnaireAdapter);
        mQuestionnaireAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new QuestionnaireAdapter.OnRecycleViewItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(View view, String data) {
                Log.i(TAG,"---->>onItemClick: " + view.getId());
                switch (view.getId()) {
                    case R.id.star_btn:
                        //do something
                        break;

                    case R.id.comment_btn:
                        //do something
                        break;

                    case R.id.forward_btn:
                        //do something
                        break;
                }
            }
        });


        return view;
    }



    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);

    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
            //mListener = null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would have done it.

Declare the buttons and their id's in the onCreate:

```
stat = (Button)findViewById(R.id.stat_btn);
cmnt = (Button)findViewById(R.id.comment_btn);
fwd = (Button)findViewById(R.id.forward_btn):
```

Then define a switch in your onClick method that listens for the button id's

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {

            case R.id.stat_btn:
                    someFunction();
                    //you can also call Log or Toast here
                break;
            case R.id.comment_btn:
                    someFunction2();
                break;
            case R.id.forward_btn:
                    someFunction3();
                break;

        }
    }
```

Comment: @ShuaiWang you haven't declared your buttons in your onCreate by using findViewById first

Comment: I do it in the 'QuestionnaireViewHolder'

Comment: @ShuaiWang As far as I understand, if you are listening for clicks on discussing id's you have to declare those id's in that activity. Or you could listen for the clicks within your holder like Shadab says

Answer (score 0):

Add OnClickListeners to the buttons in `onBindViewHolder()`

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final QuestionnaireViewHolder holder, int position) {
        //holder.tv.setText("22");
        holder.dressImageView.setImageURI(picTestUrl2);
        holder.itemView.setTag("tag");

        holder.starBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()....);
        holder.commmentBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()....);
        holder.forwardBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()....);

    }
```

No need to implement `OnItemClickListener` if you want to listen to only child views and not whole item.